# Title realignment in `moderncv`

Tags: moderncv

This might be a trivial question but I couldn't figure out how to deal with it.

I'm using this template

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} 
\moderncvstyle{casual} 
\moderncvcolor{grey} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

\firstname{First} 
\familyname{Last} 
\title{Title}
\address{address 1}{address 2}
\mobile{0000000}
\email{email}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
content

\end{document}
```

The output is like this
[image]

Is it possible to align the title and name to left and make the title nonitalic?

Comment: Add  `\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries}` before `\begin{document}`

Comment: Thank you. I see this makes the font un-italic. Do you have any suggestions for the alignment, please?

Comment: Now they are right align. Where do you want them?

Comment: The code you mentioned only changes the font from italic to not italic but does not change the alignment. I am using overleaf to compile.

Comment: I ma sorry but I do not understand  where you want to to put the name and/or the title: left margin, right margin, center .... Both together ?

Comment: I apologize. I realized there's a problem with the question. I have updated it now. I would like to move both title and name to left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title and name to  the left margin and Title non italic.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans,]{moderncv} 

\moderncvstyle[left]{casual} % changed <<<<<<<<<,

\moderncvcolor{grey} 
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} 

\firstname{First} 
\familyname{Last} 
\title{Title}
\address{address 1}{address 2}
\mobile{0000000}
\email{email}

\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \makecvtitle
    content
    
\end{document}
```